Authentication sharepoint With MFA crom c# App
I have a code which worked fine Sharepoint, but the sharepoint has Multi Factor Authentication, I read , and found it I have to change the way I was connecting to sharepoint. so I insralled PnP. Framework and this part of code
 string siteUrl = "https://ca.sharepoint.com/";
 string clientId = "MyclientId";
 string clientSecret = "pass?";
 SecureString securePassword = ConvertToSecureString(clientSecret);


 using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
 {
 cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
 cc.ExecuteQuery();
 Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);

 };

but it gives me this error

'Token request failed.'
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

but the username and password works when MFA is disabled

To the best of my knowledge MFA does not play a role when you are using app credentials to connect (GetACSAppOnlyContext).
The issue here might be that the app does not have access to target SharePoint site i.e. "https://cconsultingspa.sharepoint.com"
To troubleshoot the issue can you try to directly grant the app access to the SharePoint site by navigating to the appinv.aspx page and add the permissions XML (see reference document here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs)
Note: Using Azure ACS (Access Control Services) for SharePoint Online has been retired as of November 27th 2023. Retirement means that the feature will not get any new investments, but it's still supported. More on this here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/retirement-announcement-for-azure-acs
If the above works then the best practice would be to create an EntraID app and grant it appropriate permissions to access SharePoint data.
